# Can we use the selector field in the Cloudant query index

Tags: cloudant

If i want to limit the cloudant query 'index' to certain set of documents, can i apply a selector clause at the index creation time, the same way we apply the selector clause at the time of Cloudant query. 
Otherwise it ends up creating index for the specified field for the whole database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. However it is only for text indexes. See the [documentation here](https://docs.cloudant.com/cloudant_query.html).

Comment: any specific reason for it to be not available for "json" indexes, it would really expedite the data retrieval if i can limit the documents on "json" case also.

Comment: I don't know unfortunately.